# r markdown chunk output

Tags: r, visual-studio-code

[VS Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bQXDZ.png)

Does anyone know why when I create a new r markdown file, I have the lens options (Run Chunk, etc.), but after I save the file, the option to execute the code disappears? I tried uninstalling all of my VS extensions to see if something was preventing it, but I could not figure it out. Thank you very much.

Also, is there a way to show the code output like in R Studio? I love the output images inline in r studio, but I enjoy GitHub copilot. Thank you again.

```
summary(cars)
```

[r markdown no chunk support](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fHkdm.png)
[new rmd file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wgG2L.png)

Comment: Can you take a screenshot of the whole VS Code window? I'm wondering what VS Code shows for the file type in the bottom-right corner.

Comment: Thank you for the response @andycraig. Updating it now.

Comment: Thank you. My guess is that before it's saved it's being recognised as something other than an R Markdown file. You can check by looking at the bottom right, next to 'CRLF'. That file type probably has the lens associated with it. Then when you save the file it becomes recognised as an R Markdown file, but there's nothing providing lenses for R Markdown files. There's no 'R' logo at the left so I'm guessing you don't have an R extension installed. You could try installing this one and seeing if the lenses appear: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=REditorSupport.r